# Fix list absolute positioning (li's are hidden behind first two)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem is that when user hovers one li it makes width of li 100 percent of screen, so li needs absolute positioning to get over another li which is on the same line, but in this list I want 6 or more child, when I add other li's, it crashes. Help.

It must look like this (Full screen 50% width li's) https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP0Wd.gif

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/shotamickaia/pp658v6j/

```js
$(function(){

  $('.leftchild').hover(function(){
    $('.left').css("z-index", "2");
    $('.left').css("width", "100%");
},function(){
    $('.left').css("z-index", "0");
    $('.left').css("width", "50%");
});

    $('.rightchild').hover(function(){
    $('.right').css("z-index", "2");
    $('.right').css("width", "100%");
},function(){
    $('.right').css("z-index", "0");
    $('.right').css("width", "50%");
});
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  function setSettings() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    width = (((50 * windowWidth) / 100)*50) / 100;
    marginleft = ((((50 * windowWidth) / 100)*50) / 100) / 2;
    margintop = (((50 * windowHeight) / 100)*50) / 100;
    numitems =  $(".slides li").length;
    var myheight = (numitems * 75);

    $('.leftchild').css('width', width);
    $('.leftchild').css('marginLeft',marginleft);
    $('.leftchild').css('marginTop',margintop);
    $('.rightchild').css('width', width);
    $('.rightchild').css('marginRight',marginleft);
    $('.rightchild').css('marginTop',margintop);
  };
  setSettings();
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setSettings();
  });
});
```

```css
body,html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
 background: white;
}

#reasons {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f7f2ee;
}
.slides {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.slides li {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transition: all .4s linear;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slides li:nth-child(even) {
  z-index: 1;
  background-attachment: cover;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.slides li:nth-child(even) summary {
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.slides li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 50%;
}
.slides li summary {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}
.slides li summary h2 {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  margin: 10% 0;
}
.slides li summary p {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Andada';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.95;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="reasons">
  <div class="slider">

    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="left" style="background-image: url(content/test1.jpg); background-color:black;">
        <summary class="leftchild">
          <h2>Test 1</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>
      <li class="right" style="background-image: url(content/test2.jpg); background-color:red;">
        <summary class="rightchild">
          <h2>TEST 2</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>

      <li class="left" style="background-image: url(content/test3.jpg); background-color:black;">
        <summary class="leftchild">
          <h2>Test 3</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>
      <li class="right" style="background-image: url(content/test4.jpg); background-color:red;">
        <summary class="rightchild">
          <h2>TEST 4</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>

      <li class="left" style="background-image: url(content/test5.jpg); background-color:black;">
        <summary class="leftchild">
          <h2>Test 5</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>
      <li class="right" style="background-image: url(content/test6.jpg); background-color:red;">
        <summary class="rightchild">
          <h2>TEST 6</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>

      <li class="left" style="background-image: url(content/test7.jpg); background-color:black;">
        <summary class="leftchild">
          <h2>Test 7</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>
      <li class="right" style="background-image: url(content/test8.jpg); background-color:red;">
        <summary class="rightchild">
          <h2>TEST 8</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>

      <li class="left" style="background-image: url(content/test9.jpg); background-color:black;">
        <summary class="leftchild">
          <h2>Test 9</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>
      <li class="right" style="background-image: url(content/test10.jpg); background-color:red;">
        <summary class="rightchild">
          <h2>TEST 10</h2>
          <p>Test description</p>
        </summary>
      </li>

    </ul>




  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in pure css/html!! The only annoying bit is that you need a css declaration for every list item in order to set its initial width.

I used css `left` and `right` attributes instead of `width`, because I found that made things substantially easier.

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/gershy/k16mcgkb/2/

The idea is that all the `li` elements are absolutely positioned taking up all vertical space, and a portion of horizontal space. When an `li` is hovered its `left` and `right` are then both set to 0 (stretching all the way across its parent).

There's a neat effect as well that you will notice, that the `li` elements on either side of the hovered one become compressed. This is important because it helps avoid any `z-index` difficulties.

Here's the css that takes care of this (it's the most complicated part):

```
ul:hover > li {
    left: 0; right: 100%;
}

ul > li:hover {
    left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

ul > li:hover ~ li {
    left: 100%; right: 0;
}
```

The 1st rule says that when the `ul` is hovered, ALL `li` elements need to squish over to the left side (`left: 0;` and `right: 100%;` tell an element to have 0 width at the left side of its parent).

The 2nd rule says that the specific `li` being hovered should stretch the entire way across its parent (and gain a higher `z-index` than its siblings, just in case)

The 3rd rule is the cool part and uses a css feature I've barely ever had to use; the `~` is the "general sibling selector" and selects all elements following a certain element. This rule tells only all `li` elements that are to the right of the hovered element to squish to the right side instead of the left, overwriting the effects of the 1st rule.

I hope you don't mind the "compression" effect, I understand that you didn't ask for it.

EDIT:
It's always been stackable, here it is with several items on top of each other.
The only thing that's really been added are `!important` modifiers on the hover-resizing rules, to ensure that no matter how specific the previous style rules are, the size is modified on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/gershy/s3668f8h/

Comment: You are awesome man! Thanks, but that's not exactly what I wanted... I want only TWO Li's in one line. (not all), 5 lines (10 li's, 2 li's in each line...)

Comment: I can't do it right now but I'll get back to this! It should come down to creating 5 `ul` elements, each with 2 `li` elements inside, and stacking the `ul`s on top of each other. Will post an updated fiddle later today.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but can you post fiddle?